Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>
build.gradle (android)
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.24'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
         maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = "sk.eyJ1Ijoibm91cmFnYW1pMTYiLCJhIjoiY2x3MmRtcGZxMGhjbzJrbDhpNTd0ZG16byJ9.BUFQ6H18B-4qfDU3TG0cYA"
            }
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


this is build.gradle (android\app)
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.mapbox"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.mapbox"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-telemetry'
}

when I run my app I get this error and I do not know how to fix it ...
debug console error
this is the kind of errors I have got
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineCallback found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest$1 found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest$Builder found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineResult found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager$AccuracyAuthorization found in modules jetified-common-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.8.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)

 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).
